# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element error sending text to Email field in twitter with Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, xpath, twitter, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am getting this error when i am trying to enter username and password automatically on twitter website using Firefox browser:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .session[username_or_email]
```

The set of code i wrote so far is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://twitter.com/')
        time.sleep(3)
        bot.maximize_window()
        bot.implicitly_wait(3)
        email = bot.find_element_by_class_name('session[username_or_email]') 
        password = bot.find_element_by_class_name('session[password]')
        email.clear()
        password.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)

run = TwitterBot('jok.moe@hotmail.com', '123456')
run.login()
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element looks like:

```
<input class="js-username-field email-input js-initial-focus" type="text" name="session[username_or_email]" autocomplete="on" value="" placeholder="Phone, email or username">
```

So you could do something like:

```
email = bot.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="session[username_or_email]"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you were pretty close. To send a *character sequence* to the **Email** and **Password** fields, you have to induce WebDriverWait for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  class TwitterBot:
      def __init__(self,username,password):
          self.username = username
          self.password = password
          options = Options()
          options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe'
          self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')

      def login(self):
          bot = self.bot
          bot.get('https://twitter.com/login')
          WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.js-username-field.email-input.js-initial-focus[name='session[username_or_email]']"))).send_keys(self.username)
          bot.find_element_by_css_selector("input.js-password-field[name='session[password]']").send_keys(self.password)

  run = TwitterBot('jok.moe@hotmail.com', '123456')
  run.login()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  class TwitterBot:
      def __init__(self,username,password):
          self.username = username
          self.password = password
          options = Options()
          options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe'
          self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')

      def login(self):
          bot = self.bot
          bot.get('https://twitter.com/login')
          WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='js-username-field email-input js-initial-focus' and @name='session[username_or_email]']"))).send_keys(self.username)
          bot.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='js-password-field' and @name='session[password]']").send_keys(self.password)

  run = TwitterBot('jok.moe@hotmail.com', '123456')
  run.login()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: twitter_login]