# Selenium is not able to find the Name field in Twitter signup page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, twitter, css-selectors

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
setname = driver.find_element_by_name("name")
setname.click()
setname.send_keys("NAME SURNAME")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
emailoption = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]") #selenium can not find the element XPATH (I found it manually)
emailoption.click() #need to click in the element :)
driver.close()
```

1. Selenium can not find the element XPATH (I found it manually) ---[Use email instead](https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup)---.
2. Tried to find this element other ways... same result.
3. Maybe there is another way to click in it?

Comment: I tried `$x("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]")` in a console and ended up with an empty array. When I navigate to that element and copy its xpath, I get this `/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/span`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

action = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup')

time.sleep(5)  # Add wait here so that twitter login page will load.

NameElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='name']")
action.move_to_element(NameElement).click().perform()
NameElement.send_keys("Hello")

EmailOption = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Use email instead"]/parent::div')
EmailOption.click()

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Selenium` expected condition (`element_to_be_clickable`) to your code and use relative XPath. To input your `name`, `click` on the link and input your `email`, you can use :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='name']"))).send_keys('name')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='tel']/following::span[1]']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='email']"))).send_keys('email')
```

Be sure to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If it still fails you can use Javascript :

```
name = "your_name"
email = "your_email"
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='name']")))
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + name +"')", elem)
elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='tel']/following::span[1]']")))
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem2)
elem3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='email']")))
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + email +"')", elem3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements within [Twitter Signup](https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup) page are [React](https://reactjs.org/) elements. So to send a *character sequence* to the **Name** field you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='name']"))).send_keys("Manoel Augusto")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='name']"))).send_keys("Manoel Augusto")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: twitter_name]

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element error sending text to Email field in twitter with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583938/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-unable-to-locate-ele/59584438#59584438)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on my computer and It worked perfectly, finding the email option and clicking on it. I also found the same xpath you provided, have you tried running your program in a debugger, and What IDE/text editor are you using? Also, are you leaving the window open when you are running your program? If you close the window it will throw an error. If you have any more details on what is happening when you run your code let me know I'd love to help.

Comment: I am using PyCharm, and keep the window opened. It is a NoSuchElementException error . Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
setname = driver.find_element_by_name("name")
setname.click()
setname.send_keys("NAME SURNAME")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
element1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//div[4]")))
element1.click()
```

**Output::**

[image]